# New array aggregate function

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, unnest

I have a table like this:

```
id | array  
1  | {8,8,8,x,u,x,x}  
2  | {8,8,8,x,8,x,x}  
...|...
n  | {8,u,u,x,u,x,x}
```

It contains time of work each employee (cols in array are days of week, `u` and `x` are days free of work).
Is it possible to **aggregate** those rows into one containing sum of each col (if it's an int)?

My goal is to get from query answer like this: `{24,16,16,0,8,0,0}`

Comment: Care to explain `x` and `u`? Your Postgres version and the data type in use? Do you want to aggregate *n* rows or just combine *two*?

Comment: i need to aggregate n rows; array is made by function `string_to_array` so i assume that all data in it are strings; pgsql version is 9.0

Comment: @Vexator: reading your last comment, that is *exactly* what Erwin's answer does. Additionally in your question you say you have a **table** with an array column, now suddenly your array is the result of a function call inside a query. Please tell us what you really have.

Comment: ok, originally i have strings with are looking like this: `'09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|XE|XE'`... i need to aggregate `n` rows like this and in this aggregated cell i need to have an array. From each part of string i need only first four digits. For example: row1: `'09600480Z|XE|XE|09600480Z|...'`; row2: `'09600480Z|09600480Z|XE|XE|...'` => `{1920,960,0,960,...}` because 09600480Z = 960; XE = 0 so 09600480Z + 09600480Z = 960 + 960 = 1920; XE + 09600480Z = 0 + 960 =960;

Comment: @Vexator: Please edit your question with this essential information. Comments with data are hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `int[]` and ignoring the unexplained `x` and `u`, one way to solve it would be with `unnest()` and `row_number()`, followed by aggregation and an array constructor.

```
WITH t(i,a) AS (
   VALUES
    (1, '{8,8,8,0,0,0,0}'::int[])
   ,(2, '{8,8,8,0,8,0,0}')
   )
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT sum(elem)
   FROM  (
      SELECT unnest(a) AS elem
            ,generate_subscripts(a, 1) AS idx
      FROM   t
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY idx
   ORDER  BY idx
   );
```

Result:

```
{16,16,16,0,8,0,0}
```

The upcoming Postgres 9.4 (currently beta) provides `WITH ORDINALITY`:
[PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Simplifies things further:

```
WITH t(i,a) AS (
   VALUES
    (1, '{8,8,8,0,0,0,0}'::int[])
   ,(2, '{8,8,8,0,8,0,0}')
   )
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT sum(elem)
   FROM   unnest(a) WITH ORDINALITY AS x (elem, idx)
   GROUP  BY idx
   ORDER  BY idx
   );
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately it will not work for me :/

Comment: @Vexator: instead of obfuscating your question with `x` and `u` and "*not work*" statements you should try to say *why* Erwin's answer doesn't do what you want it to do. Given your level of requirements it's the best answer you can get. If this isn't what you are looking for you have to be **much** more specific.